# Put Force.com Functions in a Toolbar

Tags: ide, eclipse

Most of the force.come function in eclipse are buried deep in a context menu. Some (e.g. Deploy) are available in the toolbar. How do I get other functions (Refresh from Server, Run Tests) into the toolbar?

PS: Is the plugin actually alive in terms of further development? If not, I'm keen to decompile and extend the functionality (e.g. above) if no other updates are forthcoming.

Answer (score 4):

I run tests and refresh from right click (context menu) ;) Together with Mylyn plugin for tasks and context of files you currently work on it becomes quite fast workflow. (you can have local tasks, you don't really need JIRA, Bugzilla etc. tools although it's more powerful with them).

As far as I know (safe harbor, blah blah blah) Eclipse plugin will be rewritten one last time to use Tooling API instead of metadata and then handed out to the community. SF themselves will focus on changesets etc. side of things.

You might want to poke @Metadaddy and our other "inside sources", I've heard this from Adam Seligman on [meetup](http://www.meetup.com/LondonSalesforceDevelopers/events/78745732/?action=detail&eventId=78745732) but please treat it as gossip for all practical purposes ;)

Comment: Heard that at DF '11 too.  Haven't heard it recently, but hope it's still on the agenda.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really answer your question as it pertains to Eclipse, but I use the MavensMate plugin for Sublime Text 2 in lieu of Eclipse and it really has improved my development workflow. The plugin is also open sourced on GitHub so you can help improve or change the plugin as you see fit. https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate-SublimeText/

Comment: Yep, it's off topic but Sublime Text looks so awesome it makes wish I *had* a Mac.

Comment: @Marc Sublime Text 2 is available for windows (and linux).  Maven's Mate is built for mac only, but has early windows and linux support available in a pull request on github.

Comment: That's useful info thanks! I'd been using https://github.com/scripted-editor/scripted as a poor man's Sublime for JavaScript/NodeJS as I thought Sublime was Mac only!

Comment: MavensMate now available on Windows and Linux: http://mavensmate.com/Getting_Started/Downloads